# update query with multiple values

Tags: ms-access

I want to write an update query in MS Access 2003. I have a field called `product_code`.

- If product code is (between 110 and 752) OR (between 910 and 1124), I want to update product code=15.
- If product code is (between 1210 and 1213) OR (1310 and 1423) I want to assign product code=16.
- If product code is some other value I will assign 18, and so on

I don't think I can use CASE statement for this since I have many values to be updated. I tried to use multiple UPDATE/SET statements but it didn't work.

Comment: just to be clear, you want to consolidate product code 110-752 and 910-1124 into the product code 15?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a temporary table to hold your ranges and values.  Call it TableB with 3 fields LowId, HighId, NewId

```
UPDATE TableA SET TableA.ProductID=TableB.NewId
WHERE TableA.ProductID>=TableB.LowID AND TableA.ProductID<=TableB.HighId
```

Comment: This is the answer I would choose, unless I only had one or two different numbers to change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `IIF` statements to achieve this:

```
UPDATE  Products
SET Product_Code = IIF(
    (Product_Code BETWEEN 110 and 752) or 
        (Product_Code BETWEEN 910 AND 1124), 
    15,  
    IIF(
        (Product_Code BETWEEN 1210 and 1213) or 
        (Product_Code BETWEEN 1310 AND 1423), 
        16, 18
       )
    )
```

What this does is if your Product Code is between 110 and 752 or 910 and 1124, it will update the Product_Code to 15.  Otherwise, it checks to see if your code is between 1210 and 1213 or 1310 and 1423, in which case it uses 16.  Otherwise, it uses 18.

**NOTE:**  If you are updating an ID like this, make sure you have a backup of the database, or at least the table, before running this, as the previous values will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your codes and it asks for the parameter value. I am just a beginner, so I don't know what this is!?

Comment: @Ozlem -- yes, my table name was just an example since you didn't specify a table name or show any code.  You'll have to modify the query to use **your** table name.