# leaving values as they are

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a short question: I need a command to make some values stay the same in an update query with iff statement. 
Some background about my problem: I have an update query which is pretty long with 19 iff statements. Iff statements look like this;

```
UPDATE  1963
SET ProductCode = IIF(
        (ProductCode >=  8410 and ProductCode <= 8421),
        18,   and so on...
```

So basically I am updating a field according to the values in the same field. When I run the code Access 2003 gives "expression too complex" error. Since I cannot run all the code at once, I thought that I could divide the code into two parts and run separately. But once I run the first part, since this is an iff statement, the values which are not specified in the first part of the code become null. Therefore I cannot run the second part of the code since I cannot specify the range of the Product code for the second part(they all become null)
So I need a way to make the unspecified values stay the same as before in the first part, so I can run the second part to complete the code. 
That is I need something saying if (ProductCode >=  8410 and ProductCode <= 8421) set product code=18, otherwise don't change the value. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than a few If statements, it is time to look at the approach you are using. In this case, I suggest you use a table that includes the current value and the value you wish to change to, as was suggested in your previous post. You do not need a range if it does not suit, a simple one to one match is not difficult.

New Table:

```
Code  ChangeTo
8410    18
8321    18
7865     1
```

Your query would then be something like:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
INNER JOIN NewTable 
ON MyTable.Code = NewTable.Code
SET MyTableCode = NewTable.ChangeTo
```

Comment: the problem is that I am trying to update 9000 values into 19 new values. So I don't think I can use the approach you suggested?

Comment: Why not? I do not think you have 9000 distinct values to update, have you? The new table needs either a single entry for each existing code or, iIf one-to-one is a problem, a range as mentioned in your previous post.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in access so I might be wrong. In the table I have 219338 rows and I have 9000 values, so values are repeated several times. Can I use this temporary table method?

Comment: Yes, but it is not a temporary table in the sense of an SQL temporary table, it is an ordinary Access table that you can delete when it is no longer needed. It may be annoying to create, but it will certainly be less annoying that dozens of If statements.

Comment: I don't think I understood how to create this new table. I have 9000 values to be updated in the table. Are you suggesting creating "change to" column for these 9000 values?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that the ChangeTo column contains the new code, as illustrated in my answer. Is your problem with creating a table with 9000 values, if so, use a range as previously suggested, if not, what part do you not understand? BTW, it is not too difficult  to use SELECT Distinct with a  create table query to get the initial set of values from your main table.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to write 9000 values to create the new table. Can I use the ranges in "code" field of the new table?

Comment: You need to set things up a little differently, have a look at Tom B's answer to your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578826/update-query-with-multiple-values

Comment: OK. Now I got it finally! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would move the IIF conditions to the where clause and make the ProductCode high and low restrictions and the new values into parameters. Then run the query 19 times in code with different parameters. If you had a SQL Server back end, there would be a more elegant way to do this, but for a pure Access solution you'll have better luck keeping the query logic simple and making up the difference with some VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a temporary table to set the new values, then do the update regarding the temporary table.

Create new table [NewTable] based on the same structure of the old one.[without Primary Key]

```
Insert into NewTable (ID,field1,field2…..)
Select  ID,  iif(fiedl1condition,    trueValue,falseValue),………
From OldTable 

UPDATE OldTable 
INNER JOIN NewTable 
ON OldTable .ID= NewTable.ID
SET Field1 = NewTable.Field1
Field2 = NewTable.Field2
Field3 = NewTable.Field3

Drop TABLE NewTable
```

Comment: If I will write the updated values by hand then I can't see the point of arranging a temporary table. I would do this directly on the table I am updating. Am I wrong? By the way I have 9000 values to be updated!

Comment: The only reason for new table, in case you have some field related to other field in the iif condition.

Comment: @Waleed A.K. I am not sure if I understand your approach, but if I do, I do not think it is a very good idea, because it will not help with the problem of the if statements.

Comment: @Remou: i think that he has some IIF conditions that is related to other fields( as recursive),the new table will work as buffering.

Comment: I couldn't understand how to set up the new table.

Comment: @Ozlem: Just Create a table similar to the old one without primary key.